Is my transaction in a single or multiple block candidate?
When my transaction is in the memory pool, is only 1 miner allowed to pull it into his block candiate or multiple miners can have it in their block candidates?

All miners do their work independently. Your transaction can be in as many candidate blocks as the miners want as long as that transaction has not already been included in the chain.
Mining is not a cooperative work (with the exception of pools) but rather a competition, so all miners are looking to add the transactions that bring the most economic benefit to them.

There is not a single "memory pool"; each miner, and even each non-miner node have their own. Most are probably almost identical as they sort the transactions by fee, as they prefer to make as much money as possible. Some may filter out certain transactions they consider spam or include certain additional transactions that were relayed to them privately. But this is uncommon. So in most cases, all miners see your transaction and try to include it in the blocks they mine.
